# How could I augment my Tau army with Necrons?

Tags: warhammer-40k, tau, necron

I'm planning on using the 6th edition Allies rules to add some Necrons to my tau army. As a novice player I'd like to know which units would best suit this mix?

I only barely know my Tau army, and I know **nothing** of Necrons. Where do I start filling the holes in my Tau army? Why *those* pieces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Tau finally got some flyers of their own, the Necron flyers are still cheaper and better.  I would suggest using two squads of warriors in Nightscythes.  You should also run an Overlord.  He won't do much for you, but he unlocks a Royal Court.  Take one of those with a few Storm Crypteks.  Give the crypteks Voltaic staffs to shred hull points off vehicles.  Round it all out with a Doomscythe or an Annihilation Barge.

Alternatively instead of an overlord take a Destroyer Lord with a warscythe and have him lead a unit of wraiths.  Very annoying to deal with.

This will give your Tau some mobile scoring units and a little more durability.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little unclear: What is an Overlord, and a court? What do the destruction crypteks do for me? Otherwise good answer.

Comment: Overlords are the generic Necron HQ Choice.  When you take an overlord you can build a special squad called a court.  Courts are made up of lords and Crypteks.  The models in the court can be assigned to other units at the start of the game.  Destruction Crypteks can take solar pulses that can turn on or off night fighting rules.

Comment: So you wouldn't recommend wraiths, canoptek spiders etc? The fun/cool/interesting models?

Comment: Those units are good and have their place, but when taking allies you need to have other considerations in mind.  Necrons as allies give you access to cheap, fast, and resilient scoring units.  Something that Tau lacks.  You need to take these first before worrying about other options.

Comment: Well, now Tau have fliers...